# Compilation error with makefile and gtk+

Tags: gcc, compilation, compiler-errors, gtk

I have a big problem with gtk+

When i compile with my makefile, i have :

```
gcc Affichage.c -W -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: dans la fonction « _start »:
(.text+0x18): référence indéfinie vers « main »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make: *** [Affichage.o] Erreur 1
```

In Makefile, the line is :

```
Affichage.o: Affichage.c
    gcc Affichage.c -W -Wall `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```

Are you an idea ?

PS : Sorry for my bad English... I'm French

Answer (score 1):

I believe your intention was to make `Affichage.o` only a part of a big program. If it really was then you should have added `-c` flag to the rule you've given. This way it would have requested GCC to only compile `Affichage.c` but not link with CRT (assuming that you have a separate rule which links the whole of your program). And in that case you do not need to pass `--libs` flag to `pkg-config`. You should move it to the separate rule for linking.

In your case LD says it misses the entry point in your program (i.e. `main` function). I believe it resides elsewhere, not in `Affichage.c` file.